# How to create sections and section titles but prevent them from showing up in the output?

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I'm wondering if it's possible to create section and section titles but prevent them from showing up in the output. 
Below an example. Although I need the section for the numbering op my tables and figures I don't want the title in my ouput

`\appendix 
 \section{the first appendix}`

Comment: If you need the numbers only, you can use `\stepcounter{section}`. This will increase the relevant section number, but do you want to have the section titles in the `ToC` anyway?

Comment: I think, it's better to use `\refstepcounter{section}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either one uses `\refstepcounter{section}` directly each time or  `\fakesection` command that does `\refstepcounter{section}` or redefines `\section` to do effectively nothing apart from `\refstepcounter{section}`.

In my point of view, it's better to redefine `\section` to provide the possibility of using the same code later on when section titles and toc entries are needed.

I've done this here by appending the redefinition code to the `\appendix` command, i.e. it's redefined only after `\appendix` has been used.

**Why `\refstepcounter` and not just `\stepcounter`**?

Assume, that the (non-existent) appendix section should be referenced by a `\label` command → this would only work with `\refstepcounter{section}` and not with `\stepcounter` only!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xpatch}



\makeatletter
\let\latex@@section\section
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \renewcommand{\section}[2][]{%
    \refstepcounter{section}%
  }
  \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection.\arabic{figure}}
}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A real section}

\clearpage
\appendix

\section{A dummy section}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=2]{beeduck}
\caption{ A figure in a dummy section}
\end{figure}




\end{document}
```